# Whats the point of having a disabled broadcast reciever?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I came across this piece of code :

```
<receiver android:name=".SampleBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

While reading about AlarmManager [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), and i dont get why would they declare their reciever as enabled=false? why wouldnt they want the system to be able to instiantiate their reciever and in general whats the point of declaring a reciever on XML that can not be instantiated by the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i dont get why would they declare their reciever as enabled=false?

Because the receiver is not always needed.

> why wouldnt they want the system to be able to instiantiate their reciever

Because the receiver is not always needed.

> whats the point of declaring a reciever on XML that can not be instantiated by the system?

Because the receiver can be enabled later on when it *is* needed.

For example, suppose you are implementing something like the Download application, which is what provides the implementation for `DownloadManager`. While downloading a file, perhaps the device reboots. Ideally, you would like to resume the download after the reboot is complete. However, most of the time, a file is not being downloaded, and so you do not normally need to get control at boot time.

The lazy approach is to say that you will *always* get control at boot time, see if there was an outstanding download at the time of the reboot, restart the download if there was, and just go away if there was not. This is wasteful, as it forces Android to fork a process for you and go through a bunch of process setup work, when in the end, you will not do anything for the user.

The better approach is to have the boot-completed receiver be disabled normally. When a request to download a file comes in, enable the receiver using `setComponentEnabledSetting()` on `PackageManager`, then disable it again when the download is completed. Now, only on the reboots where there is an in-progress download will you get control at boot time, speeding up the boot process for the rest of the time.

More generally, if you want to listen for broadcasts (particularly system ones) from a manifest-registered receiver, *but only some of the time*, you would enable and disable the receiver in Java code using `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. Typically, you start off with the receiver being disabled, but that's not a strict requirement.